# Proper pushforward

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation

I am studying a some intersection theory. Now I am stuck on the proof of the Lemma 02R6 [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02R3). More precisely, I don't understand why the coeffiecient of $Z$ in $[f_\ast\mathcal{F}]_k$ is equal to $\text{length}_{R_{\mathfrak p}}(M_{\mathfrak p})$. Can you help me?

Comment: This just follows from the definition of $[f_*\mathcal{F}]$ - note here $\mathfrak{p}$ is the generic point of $Z$.

Comment: I don't understand because it is not $\deg(Z/f(Z))\text{length}_{R_{\mathfrak p}}(M_{\mathfrak p})$. Can you expand your answer?

Comment: The degree of $f$ doesn't really matter here - it would show up if you were computing $f_*[\mathcal{F}]_k$ ( and in particular you see this expression later), but here you're looking at $[f_*\mathcal{F}]_k$! 

In other words what's happening is you have a coherent sheaf ($\mathcal{G}:= f_*\mathcal{F})$ on $Y$ and you're just trying to compute its corresponding cycle.